# Multi-page Django form with several models and views

Tags: django, forms, validation, flags

I'm working on an existing system that has several forms that fill a group of models on Django, but they are related to one another and are split across some tab components to fill.

My objective is to make several fields `required` and a way to get that info anywhere on the system, if X form was already completely filled with the required fields or not. There is a validation on the forms, but it only happens if the user actually presses the save button, if he simply leaves the page or doesn't even enter that tab, the system ignores it.

Each form when completed is saving on the database that part individually, and that's good, because the user may not have all the info at once, but I need a way to alert:

- If the user didn't fill all the forms to let him know that it will not be validated by an admin until he does so.
- A flag so that the admin knows that the user didn't complete everything yet and doesn't waste time with it.

I tried to make a custom `save` function on the models, that would save a flag based if some values were `not None`, but since there are a lot of foreign relations and some models are filled on more than one page that could be hard.

Another thing I'm trying right now is getting the form instance on the main view, but for some reason or it's returning an incomplete form, or the `is_valid()` is not working on those instances.

I was also taking a look at `FormWizard`, but looks like it doesn't save on the database after each step, and is terribly complicated to implement on an already running system.

Any tips are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: If you're needing to do things in the for based on the values from another object, get the object in the view that renders your form & pass `kwargs` to your form that you can then use in the `__init__` of the form to modify it. Shouldn't be a need to modify the save if thats what you want. Give it a go then post some code of specifically doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly what you want is a way of tracking down whether a user has filled out all of your forms or not. If that is the case I'd suggest adding a model whose purpose is to track down precisely that. Something in the form of:

```
class UserFormTracking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_MODEL, ..., unique=True)
    form1_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
    formn_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def all_completed(self):
        return self.form1_completed and ... and self.formk_completed
```

Then I would override each form's `save()` method with something like the following (assuming this is the `save()` method of the K-th form):

```
def save(self, user, **kwargs):
    instance = super(MyForm, self).save(**kwargs)
    forms_tracking_instance = UserFormTracking.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    forms_tracking_instance.formk_completed = True
    forms_tracking_instance.save()

    return instance
```

Note that you need to pass the user to the `save()` method. This would probably come out from the http request, but this could vary. Afterwards all that is remaining to check whether a user `u` has filled out every form is to query the `UserFormTracking` model for an instance whose user is `u` and every `formk_completed` is set to `True`.
Bear in mind that in order to prevent inconsistencies you would probably want to execute the overriden `save()` methods of your forms inside a transaction.

Of course this is a rather fixed solution. If your application is likely to change frequently (in the sense of adding or removing forms) you will need to come out with a more flexible solution. But you can follow the same idea.

Comment: I like the idea, I'll try to implement something like this on my next work day and post the results here. Thanks.